# The rattle Annotation option doesn't seem to work

Tags: r, rstudio, rattle

rattle version 5.2.0 (or 5.2.5) doesn't seem to annotate  graphs under the Explorer tab - Distributions - Box Plot.  I can recode it and get the desired look but click / unclicking Annotate doesn't seem to do any thing.

RStudio version 1.1.463, 
  R version 3.5.1, 
  rattle version 5.2.0

MIght there be another library I'm missing?

Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the solution was to uncheck Advanced Graphics under the Settings drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Annotate is not fully implemented everywhere, and in particular on the newer graphics in rattle where we are gradually migrating to ggplot2.

For the specific example you mention, Explore -> Distributions -> Box Plot, the plot is actually annotated always (even when Annotated in unchecked) in that it shows the means in each box.

Specific examples of code to illustrate the actual annotations you were expecting to see are most welcome.